# Implementing imageswitcher

Tags: android

i am trying to display all the images in my sdcard using gallery and imageswitcher. What i am trying to do is when i look at my gallery i want to be able to select a picture and give the user an option to upload the picture to the website or delete the picture.

i am not able to figure out how to implement onclick along with imageswticher.

Any insight will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a GestureDetector
- Add an onTouchListener to your imageswitcher.

You then have a method that returns which gesture was done on the imageswitcher, and there you can handle it.